# gnome-shell extension crashes repeatedly with GLib-ERROR: Creating pipes for GWakeup: too many open files

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

After upgrading Ubuntu, my desktop icons keep popping up and disappearing in 1 second intervals rendering the desktop unusable.

through the `journalctl`, I see the following error repeatedly:

```
10月 12 22:42:57 ubuntu-22 nautilus[8793]: Could not delete '.meta.isrunning': No such file or direct>
10月 12 22:42:58 ubuntu-22 gnome-shell[1748]: DING: (gjs:8778): GLib-ERROR **: 14:42:58.680: Creating>
10月 12 22:43:00 ubuntu-22 dbus-daemon[1627]: [session uid=1000 pid=1627] Activating service name='or>
10月 12 22:43:00 ubuntu-22 dbus-daemon[1627]: [session uid=1000 pid=1627] Successfully activated serv>
10月 12 22:43:01 ubuntu-22 dbus-daemon[1627]: [session uid=1000 pid=1627] Activating service name='or>
10月 12 22:43:01 ubuntu-22 dbus-daemon[1627]: [session uid=1000 pid=1627] Successfully activated serv>
10月 12 22:43:01 ubuntu-22 gnome-shell[1748]: DING: Detected async api for thumbnails
10月 12 22:43:01 ubuntu-22 gnome-shell[1748]: DING: GNOME nautilus 42.6
```

I also note that the gjs has a highly cpu usage.
I search the network, find that there have a same problem, but no answer.
how could i solve this problem ?

Comment: @Bit-cat did you fixed this issue? I am facing same issue